# Apache-JENA-2.12.1 database connection jar files

Tags: eclipse, jena

My question is, does Apache-JENA-2.12.1 have the com.hp.hpl.jena.db jar file?

Because I have this highlighted error in Eclipse:

`IDBConnection conn = new DBConnection( dbURL, dbUser,dbPw, dbType );
->>> IDBConnection cannot be resolved to a type`

It's the first time that i'm working in a semantic project. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That code, for the original SQL databases-backed storage, was removed a long time ago.

Nowadays, the persistent storage system, provides is TDB, with one called SDB is you really, really must use an SQL database.  TDB is faster and scales better than SDB, and is integrated with Fuseki.